# Jquery : on check of an option in checkbox show a textbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a list of `checkbox` , when the user clicks on the `others option`, a `text field` opens. This works fine in scenario 1, but does not work in scenario 2.
**Scenario 1**: user first selects option cat and then others option, then text field shows as expected. [works fine, text field shows as expected]
**Scenario 2**: If user selects others option first(text field shows intially), but if he selects cat option after that text field hides.[text field disappears]

Please find the below code:

```
$(".animals").change(function () {
    //check if its checked. If checked move inside and check for others value
    if (this.checked && this.value === "other") {
        //add a text box next to it
        $("#other-text").show();
    } else {
        //remove if unchecked
        $("#other-text").hide();
    }
});
```

This is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Kritika/XSzKu/

How do i make it work for scenario 2 also?.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check to see if the other checkbox is unchecked before you hide the textbox

```
$(".animals").change(function () {
    //check if its checked. If checked move inside and check for others value
    if (this.checked && this.value === "other") {
        //add a text box next to it
        $("#other-text").show();
    } 
    else if (!this.checked && this.value === "other") {
        //remove if unchecked
        $("#other-text").hide();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XSzKu/1/

Answer (score 2):

you can use the below JS

```
$(".animals").change(function () {
    //check if the selected option is others
    if (this.value === "other") {
        //toggle textbox visibility
        $("#other-text").toggle();
    }
});
```